# How do I convert byte[] array to byte type variable?

Tags: android, arrays, byte

I am working on Android. And I am getting byte array from image file. My requirement is that to send a byte type variable to server, instead of byte array.

But I am getting Byte array, then I want convert that byte array to byte variable.

My code is like

```
  InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
  byte[] imageData = readBytes(in);

  byte  bytedata = // here I want get the bytes from imageData array


 public byte[] readBytes(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {

      ByteArrayOutputStream byteBuffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();


      int bufferSize = 1024;
      byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];


      int len = 0;
      while ((len = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byteBuffer.write(buffer, 0, len);

      }

      // and then we can return your byte array.
      return byteBuffer.toByteArray();
    }
```

Comment: You can convert it into a string bytearay.toString(); and send it through the network

Comment: if you can send a byte, try sending a stream of bytes over the network one by one.!

Answer (score 1):

How would you expect to convert an array of byte to a single byte? It's like converting n things to one thing. You may try sending the array's elements one by one as they are of byte type, but otherwise I don't see how you can achieve what you try.

Comment: @Selvin well then let OP simply send 42 over the network as we know 42 is the ultimate answer